# Cannot access url https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token

Tags: api, rest, oauth

My customer's webmaster uses REST API to create Leads in salesforce, from his website.
Since yesterday he is getting a connection error.
The password has not changed. I tried to make a call from a rest api client, with the same username and password, and it worked fine.

Here's the detail:

```
object(SalesForce_API_REST_Transport_Stream_Exception)#3142 (8) {
  ["transport":"SalesForce_API_REST_Transport_Exception":private]=>
  object(SalesForce_API_REST_Transport_Stream)#3140 (0) {
  }
  ["message":protected]=>
  string(96) "Cannot access url 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token' (111: Connection refused)"
  ["string":"Exception":private]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["code":protected]=>
  int(0)
  ["file":protected]=>
  string(113) "/data/vhosts/i/iso.fr/wordpress/wp-content/themes/iso/vendors/salesforce/SalesForce_API_REST_Transport_Stream.php"
  ["line":protected]=>
  int(41)
  ["trace":"Exception":private]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(6) {
      ["file"]=>
      string(96) "/data/vhosts/i/iso.fr/wordpress/wp-content/themes/iso/vendors/salesforce/SalesForce_API_REST.php"
      ["line"]=>
      int(64)
      ["function"]=>
      string(7) "request"
      ["class"]=>
      string(36) "SalesForce_API_REST_Transport_Stream"
      ["type"]=>
      string(2) "->"
      ["args"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        object(SalesForce_API_REST_Request)#3141 (4) {
          ["url":protected]=>
          string(50) "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token"
          ["headers":protected]=>
          array(2) {
            ["Accept"]=>
            string(16) "application/json"
            ["Content-Type"]=>
            string(48) "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
          }
          ["method":protected]=>
          string(4) "POST"
          ["body":protected]=>
          string(224) "grant_type=password&client_id=3MVG99qusVZJwhsm8gwtmpoI7gU8FTL7hAR2QaRNq488PIXF.c_XUkna92btE4SW9vvINw0zY7r.7tF4vtgbZ&client_secret=9185831519385046154&username=valerie.petat%40iso.fr&password=1_JSimonIoQKPPiSG86Xs1Pfxo9nkpwId"
        }
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    array(6) {
      ["file"]=>
      string(62) "/data/vhosts/i/iso.fr/wordpress/wp-content/themes/iso/cron.php"
      ["line"]=>
      int(150)
      ["function"]=>
      string(12) "authenticate"
      ["class"]=>
      string(19) "SalesForce_API_REST"
      ["type"]=>
      string(2) "->"
      ["args"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        int(3)
      }
    }
  }
  ["previous":"Exception":private]=>
  NULL
}
```

Have you ever had this error before?

Thanks,
Anne

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this problem occurs at random intervals then: 
I have faced this problem in one of nightly job. When contacted support they mentioned that it was due to momentary performance degradation on that pod.

So the only option is to implement Re-Try functionality to handle this failures.

If its permanent issue then:

There is issue with network connection on your webmaster server. some how it can not connect to sales force server.

I dont think there is any issue with user/pass as it give different error for that.